# how to attach a onClick Listener to a listview item on an app widget

Tags: android, listview, android-appwidget

I like to add a onClick Listener to every item of my listview, but nothing what I have tried work.

Here is my RemoteViewsFactory:

```
public class MyRemoteViewsFactory implements RemoteViewsService.RemoteViewsFactory {

    [...]

    public RemoteViews getViewAt(int position) {

        final RemoteViews remoteView = new RemoteViews(
            context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_item);

        [...]

        final Intent activityIntent = new Intent(context, ListActivity.class);
        activityIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);
        activityIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_PICK, position);
        PendingIntent pI = PendingIntent.getActivity(
            context, appWidgetId, activityIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        remoteView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.item_frame, pI);

        return remoteView;
    }
}
```

list-widget.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/widget_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" >

    <include layout="@layout/picture_frame" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/picframe"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:loopViews="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

list-item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/item_frame"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/date"
        style="@style/WidgetItemText" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        style="@style/WidgetItemText" />

</LinearLayout>
```

If I click an item, nothing is happen.

The intent works properly, if I hang it in the provider directly to the listview, but then I can no longer scroll and not respond to individual items.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The section of **Adding behavior to individual items** in the [official doc](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html) say:

> As described in Using the AppWidgetProvider Class, you normally use setOnClickPendingIntent() to set an object's click behavior—such as to cause a button to launch an Activity. But this approach is not allowed for child views in an individual collection item (to clarify, you could use setOnClickPendingIntent() to set up a global button in the Gmail app widget that launches the app, for example, but not on the individual list items). Instead, to add click behavior to individual items in a collection, you use setOnClickFillInIntent(). This entails setting up up a pending intent template for your collection view, and then setting a fill-in intent on each item in the collection via your RemoteViewsFactory.
>
> Your RemoteViewsFactory must set a fill-in intent on each item in the collection. This makes it possible to distinguish the individual on-click action of a given item. The fill-in intent is then combined with the PendingIntent template in order to determine the final intent that will be executed when the item is clicked.

Your need to call `setOnClickFillInIntent` to differentiate the item on-click behavior. Something like this:

```
public RemoteViews getViewAt(int position) {

        final RemoteViews remoteView = new RemoteViews(
            context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_item);

        [...]

        // Next, set a fill-intent, which will be used to fill in the pending intent template
        // that is set on the collection view in StackWidgetProvider.
        Bundle extras = new Bundle();
        extras.putInt(YouWidgetProvider.EXTRA_ITEM, position);
        Intent fillInIntent = new Intent();
        fillInIntent.putExtras(extras);
        // Make it possible to distinguish the individual on-click
        // action of a given item
        remoteView.setOnClickFillInIntent(R.id.item_frame, fillInIntent);


        return remoteView;
    }
```

Also `setPendingIntentTemplate` should be use instead of `setOnClickPendingIntent` to set a single `PendingIntent` template on the collection. Set the pending intent in `onUpdate` method corresponding to you subclass of `AppWidgetProvider`, something like this:

```
@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        // update each of the app widgets with the remote adapter
        for (int i = 0; i < appWidgetIds.length; ++i) {
            ...
            RemoteViews remoteView = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), 
                R.layout.widget_item);
            ...

            // This section makes it possible for items to have individualized behavior.
            // It does this by setting up a pending intent template. Individuals items of a collection
            // cannot set up their own pending intents. Instead, the collection as a whole sets
            // up a pending intent template, and the individual items set a fillInIntent
            // to create unique behavior on an item-by-item basis.
            Intent activityIntent = new Intent(context, ListActivity.class);
            // Set the action for the intent.
            // When the user touches a particular view.
            activityIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetIds[i]);
            activityIntent.setData(Uri.parse(intent.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)));
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, appWidgetIds[i], 
                activityIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            remoteView.setPendingIntentTemplate(R.id.stack_view, pendingIntent);

            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds[i], remoteView);
        }
        super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for a great answer. I'd like to also point out that if you set an extra with the same key on both sides, the extra value set in `onUpdate()` will override the any value set in `getViewAt()`.

Answer (score 0):

> With this `Code` you can add onClick for every ListView item in Widget and can pass data from widget item to start new `Activity` with this data.

In the widgets, you can not create an individual `Intent` for every item in the list or stack. In order to do this, we have to create `Intent` with data in `WidgetService` for every list item that we create.

This is `WidgetService.java`. I created a `new Intent` with Extra data I want to send. 
Then I choose which UI element will be a trigger `views.setOnClickFillInIntent` in this function.

```
  @Override
    public RemoteViews getViewAt(int position) {
        final RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_item);

        //Open Post
        Intent fillIntent = new Intent();
        fillIntent.putExtra(
                "keyData", position);
        views.setOnClickFillInIntent(R.id.tvTitle, fillIntent);

    .....
   }
```

This is `ExampleWidgetProvider.java`

```
public static final String ACTION_POST = "actionPost";

@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    // update each of the app widgets with the remote adapter
    for (int i = 0; i < appWidgetIds.length; ++i) {
        ...
        RemoteViews remoteView = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), 
            R.layout.listview);


        ...


        Intent postIntent = new Intent(context, ExampleWidgetProvider.class);
        postIntent.setAction(ACTION_POST);
        PendingIntent postPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,
                0, postIntent, 0);


        ...


            activityIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        remoteView.setPendingIntentTemplate(R.id.listview, postPendingIntent );

        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds[i], remoteView);
    }
    super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
}
```

We have already created OnClick for every `ListView` item which will send intent to itself to this `ExampleWidgetProvider.java`. Now we have to read the information that we send by `Intent` in `WidgetService.java` for every List Item.

To do this we have to create another function in `ExampleWidgetProvider.java`.

```
@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if(ACTION_POST.equals(intent.getAction())){

            //Passed info from WidgetService.java
            String data= intent.getStringExtra("keyData");

            // If you want to open new activity with this data you can do it
            Intent intentPOST = new Intent(context,
                    MainActivity.class).putExtra(
                    "keyData", data);
            intentPOST.setFlags (Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity (intentPOST);


            //Show information
            Toast.makeText(context,
                    data,
                   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        super.onReceive(context, intent);
    }
```

Comment: So this does not work for me because it seems to be putting `keyData` into the extra object of the `fillIntent` but the `postIntent` is the one being received by `onRecieve` so I get a `null` value for `keyData` when I try to get it via `intent.getStringExtra("keyData")`

Answer (score -3):

You could try something like that, where position is the index of your item in the listview

```
ListView lv = getListView();
setContentView(lv);
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
{
@Override 
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int position, long arg3)
{ 
    Toast.makeText(SuggestionActivity.this, "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
});
```

Comment: Hi;
where should I do that? RemoteViewsFactory does not have a getListView() Method. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViewsService.RemoteViewsFactory.html

Comment: You could do: `ListView l= (ListView) findViewById (R.layout.file_that_you_inflate);` and then `l.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
{
@Override 
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int position, long arg3)
{ 
    Toast.makeText(SuggestionActivity.this, "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
});`

Comment: this doesn't work. we are talking about app widget, not a normal activity.